# --prod flag causes no showing of Keyboard in Ionic 3 app with Android 7

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

when I run: `ionic cordova run android --device` everything is fine but when I try with the `--prod` flag. The input click does not show the keyboard even thought I used the `(onFocus)` attribute of `<ion-input>`.

Here is my ionic info:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Houssem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.3
    npm               : 5.5.1
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Houssem\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** You need to use `@ionic/app-scripts@3.1.7` or greater.

**Explanation:** There was an injection of `uglify-es` module (version was incompatible: caused your issue) in previous versions. So in `3.1.7` was hotfix, where `uglify-es` version was decreased to the compatible one.